# Version Conflict same Project DevExpress

Tags: c#, dll, devexpress, version, conflicting-libraries

I have one dll that uses a version 16.2 of DevExpress, this dll is used to show one form.

- Basically I want to install this dll in a project that constains all references in DevExpress 14.
- When I create my dll, I merge all DevExpress 16.2 in the dll, and I put in NuGet, when I download in the project (DevExpress 14) has conflicts between the types, that are present in both versions.

Anyone know if I can use the dll of DevExpress 16.2 only when my dll need to be runned? Or anyway to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

let me see if I understand, so you want to use two versions of DevExpress in the same project?

Why don't upgrade the entire project to v16?

I never mixed dlls vresions because it is really crazy, but if it helps to you when I upgrade and look at the **bin** folder I **must delete the old dlls and just keep the new ones, yes that means remove the old references, etc** that solves the conflict.

DevExpress has a wizard to upgrate the entire project including the config and all the files.

Comment: Yes, this is what I would to do, but is out of context because, is not one application that use DevExpress different versions, and if I did about this way, I need to migrate every applications that use my dll.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , my temporary solution is remove all DevExpress references and leave the project all in windows forms.